# get error tag is not a valid filter field at onesignal api

Tags: java, android, onesignal

i am send notification with onesignal api

```
String strJsonBody = "{"
                              +   "\"app_id\": \"" + APP_ID + "\","
                              +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                              +   "\"filters\": [{\"field\": \"tag \", \"key \": \"" + key + " \", \"relation \": \"=\", \"value\": \"1\"}],"
                              +   "\"data\": {\"news_id\": \"" + newsId + "\"},"
                              +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"" + newsTitle + "\"}"
                              + "}";
```

and get error {"errors":["  tag  is not a valid filter field."]}

Answer (score 0):

remove all space between word

```
String strJsonBody = "{"
                          +   "\"app_id\": \"" + APP_ID + "\","
                          +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                          +   "\"filters\": [{\"field\": \"tag\", \"key\": \"" + key + "\", \"relation \": \"=\", \"value\": \"1\"}],"
                          +   "\"data\": {\"news_id\": \"" + newsId + "\"},"
                          +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"" + newsTitle + "\"}"
                          + "}";
```